# how to disable anythingslider forward button onlast slide and back button on first page?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

I am using Jquery component "anythingslider" great plugin from http://css-tricks.com/anythingslider-jquery-plugin/  but there is small problem, I want to disable back button when its displaying 1st slide i.e 1st

element and disable forward button when its displaying last slide i.e last

element ?

There are total 8

elements in the slider

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following code

```
    $('#slider').anythingSlider({
        onInitialized   : function(){
              // hide back arrow
              $('.arrow.back').hide();
        },
        onSlideComplete     : function(){
            if($('#slider .panel:not(.cloned)').first().hasClass('activePage')){
              // hide back arrow
              $('.arrow.back').hide();
            }
            else{
              $('.arrow.back').show();
            }

            if($('#slider .panel:not(.cloned)').last().hasClass('activePage')){
              // hide forward  arrow
              $('.arrow.forward').hide();
            }
            else{
              $('.arrow.forward').show();
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

the plugin is based on LI structure and current (active) li has class 'activePage'
code:

```
$('.arrow.back')click(
function(e){
   if($('ul#slider1').find('li:not(.cloned)').first().hasClass('activePage')){
      e.stopImmediatePropagation();
      return false;
}});
```

the id's and classes were investigated from the page source,
hope this will somehow help you
if this will be a first event listener in queue, it could work