# Try to hide previous arrow on first slide while using appendBackTo

Tags: anythingslider

I achieve to hide previous arrow on first slide, and next arrow on last slide using :

```
infiniteSlides: false,
stopAtEnd: true,
```

but when I'm using :

```
appendBackTo: $('#nav-slider'),
appendForwardTo: $('#nav-slider2'),
```

the arrow I would like to hide are not hiding..

Do I miss something..?

The whole code below:

```
<script>
    // DOM Ready
    $(function(){
        $('#slider')
            .anythingSlider({
                appendBackTo: $('#nav-slider  span:eq(0)'),
                appendForwardTo: $('#nav-slider  span:eq(1)'),
                forwardText: "dhdgd<img height='20' width='20' src='http://eofdreams.com/data_images/dreams/image/image-07.jpg'>",
                backText: "<img height='20' width='20' src='http://eofdreams.com/data_images/dreams/image/image-07.jpg'>dhdgd",
                resizeContents      : true,
                addWmodeToObject    : 'opaque',
                buildNavigation     : false,
                buildStartStop     : false,
                infiniteSlides: false,
                stopAtEnd: true
            })
            // Initialize video extension
            // see https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters?hl=en#Parameters for a list of parameters
            .anythingSliderVideo({
                // video id prefix; suffix from $.fn.anythingSliderVideo.videoIndex
                videoId : 'asvideo',

            });
    });
</script>
```

Thanks a lot !

Comment: found the solution here:

Answer (score 0):

found the solution here 2
[how to disable anythingslider forward button onlast slide and back button on first page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15155377/how-to-disable-anythingslider-forward-button-onlast-slide-and-back-button-on-fir)

Use the following code

```
    $('#slider').anythingSlider({
        onInitialized   : function(){
              // hide back arrow
              $('.arrow.back').hide();
        },
        onSlideComplete     : function(){
            if($('#slider .panel:not(.cloned)').first().hasClass('activePage')){
              // hide back arrow
              $('.arrow.back').hide();
            }
            else{
              $('.arrow.back').show();
            }

            if($('#slider .panel:not(.cloned)').last().hasClass('activePage')){
              // hide forward  arrow
              $('.arrow.forward').hide();
            }
            else{
              $('.arrow.forward').show();
            }
        }
    });
```